# Is the preimage of a characteristic subgroup characteristic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, characteristic-subgroups

If $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism and $K \triangleleft H$, then $\phi^{-1}(K) \triangleleft G$.

What can be said in the case where $K$ is characteristic in $H$?

Comment: Consider for instance $K=\{e\}\triangleleft H$ and the map $\pi:H\times H\to H$, $\pi(x,y)=x$.